# Progress bar not update in notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

I want to update notification from another activity and I declare it on the service class, I make log also a log is print mean method call but can't update notification progress bar value.

**MyNotyficationService** class below and my notification code write in this class.

```
public class MyNotyficationService extends Service {
    public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "channelForground";
    public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "com.example.notificationdemo";
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel;
    NotificationManager manager;
    RemoteViews contentView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        contentView = new RemoteViews("com.example.android", R.layout.notification_layout_custom);

        showNotification("0");

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    public void updateNoty(int per){
        Log.d("CALL__m","call" +per);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.battery_level_Status, "Downloading : " + per + "%");
        contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar_notification_current_battery_level, 100, per, false);
        manager.notify(42, notification.build());
    }

    public void showNotification(String body) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            if (manager != null) {
                manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
        }

        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.battery_level_Status, "Downloading : " + body + "%");
        contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar_notification_current_battery_level, 100, Integer.parseInt(body), false);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cat_drinking)
                    .setContent(contentView);
        } else {
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setContent(contentView)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cat_drinking);
        }
        startForeground(10, notification.build());
    }
    private void startService_() {
        Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyNotyficationService.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(restartService);
        } else {
            startService(restartService);
        }
        PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, restartServicePI);
    }


    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        startService_();
    }
}
```

And I want to update notification progress from another activity class, so what I do for that?

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  public MyNotyficationService myNotyficationService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_screen_image);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ForegroundService.class);
                ContextCompat.startForegroundService(HomeActivity.this, serviceIntent);
            } else {
                startService(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ForegroundService.class));
            }

        myNotyficationService= new MyNotyficationService();
        myNotyficationService.updateNoty(50);
   }
```

In my service class, I declare below method and I got log value but can't update notification progress

```
 public void updateNoty(int per){
        Log.d("CALL__m","call" +per);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.battery_level_Status, "Downloading : " + per + "%");
        contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar_notification_current_battery_level, 100, per, false);
        manager.notify(42, notification.build());
    }
```

**if anyone has another solution for that then share your answer**

My Custom ContentView is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/notification_image_icon"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_notification_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notification_image_icon"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#323232" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/battery_level_Status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notification_image_icon"
            android:text="50%"
            android:textColor="#323232" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar_notification_current_battery_level"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/notificationprogress" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My manifest for service class init

```
<service
            android:name=".Acivity.ForegroundService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
```

Comment: are you using contentView  custom?

Comment: Yes, I added my content view in question.

Comment: `DownloadManager` provides such a progress bar ...

Comment: @PrafulKorat where do you init `myNotyficationService`?

Comment: @Nhất Giang in menifest, i added in que now

Comment: @PrafulKorat I mean where do you init `myNotyficationService` variable in HomeActivity. Because from your code, this line `myNotyficationService.updateNoty(50);` will make your app crash.

Comment: yes in above i use `myNotyficationService.updateNoty(50);` ,i added it

Comment: @PrafulKorat In Android you cannot create a service like `myNotyficationService= new MyNotyficationService();`, and call methods on it. First, you need to register the service with Android system, second call `startService()` or `startForegroundService()`, then Android will create and start the service for you. If you want to update status of progress bar, then you can send broadcast from your activity to service, then service will update the progress.

Comment: Yes , i also call that method but i forgot write into code.check now.

Comment: try adding post delayed on ui thread, you ui thread must be busy so add update action in the queue xd

Comment: @PrafulKorat as I said, you cannot create an instance of Service, in this case you should send a broadcast to your service instead of creating a service and call `updateNotify()` method on it.

Comment: An example of a code sample for it? then share link or code

Comment: use Messenger to send data form activty to running serivce. for ref see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736714/how-to-pass-data-from-activity-to-running-service#answer-43737298

Answer (score 1):

This is what i am doing to update notification from service but i am using NotificationCompat.Builder object to set progress and text.

```
  private void raiseNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder b, int counter) {
    b.setContentText("Downloaded " + counter + "% ");
    b.setProgress(100, counter, false);
    b.setOngoing(true);
    if (counter > 99) {
        b.setAutoCancel(true);
        b.setOngoing(false);
        b.setContentTitle("Download complete").setProgress(0, 0, false);
    }
    if (mgr != null) mgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, b.build());
}
```

Comment: Sure what i am telling you that when you set text through NotificationCompat.Builder b it working in my case so  is that not working  in your case?

Comment: @PrafulKorat ok let me create demo with your code will let you know